# Using & in Command with align

Tags: pdftex, align, ampersand

I have written a small command:

```
\newcommand{\LH}[1]{
\underset{\text{\enquote{$#1$}}}{\overset{\text{L' H}} {=\joinrel=\joinrel=}}
}
```

For using L' Hospitals Rule. The whole text needs three === and I want to align the last = with the current & in my align environment. However if I use `=\joinrel=\joinrel & =` it doesnt work. Any Idea on how to make it work?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\LH}[1]{
\underset{\text{\enquote{$#1$}}}{\overset{\text{L' H}} {=\joinrel=\joinrel=}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x) &= \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
    f(0) &= \lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)\\
    &\LH{\frac{0}{0}} \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{1} \right)\\
    &= 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `&` to the other side of the relations.  However (because of the way `amsmath` works), you must then also add a `{}` to let the relation know there is something that follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\LH}[1]{
\underset{\text{\enquote{$#1$}}}{\overset{\text{L' H}} {=\joinrel=\joinrel=}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x) ={}& \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
    f(0) ={}& \lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)\\
    \LH{\frac{0}{0}}{}& \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{1} \right)\\
    ={}& 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If only the last equation in the set needs numbering (for future reference), one can use a `tabstackengine` approach that eliminates the need to type the extra `{}` each time, with a little bit of preamble setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\TABbinary
\setstackgap{S}{6pt}
\newcommand{\LH}[1]{
\underset{\text{\enquote{$#1$}}}{\overset{\text{L' H}} {=\joinrel=\joinrel=}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:myeq}
\alignShortstack{
    f(x) =& \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\\
    f(0) =& \lim_{x\to 0}\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right)\\
    \LH{\frac{0}{0}}& \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{\cos(x)}{1} \right)\\
    =& 1
}
\end{equation}
In equation~\ref{eq:myeq} above\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did the job for me, thank you very much. Is there an "easier" way to get the job done? Since you have to put `={}&` every time

Comment: @Mattis If you didn't need each equation numbered, there could be a `tabstackengine` solution that would be easier, but it doesn't have the ability to number each equation in the alignment.

Comment: Thats unfortunatly no option since i always need (at least) the last equation numberd and possibly referenced

Comment: @Mattis See my edit.

Comment: To be honest I think that's more work and I just figured out you can also use `=~&`, which is a way better shortcut. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Mattis -- The problem with `~` is that the space is wider than the default space before/after an `=`.  The `{}` produces the default space.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT answer**:

I will use `\xlongequal[]{...}` from Table 260: `extarrows` Extensible Arrows instead a macro from the symbols guide. I have deleted the macro and I have used `\mbox{‘‘}` and the `\mbox{\quotedblbase}` to put the quotes. You can change them the position, and I have aligned the `\xlongequal[]{...}` to the right using a negative space: `\mkern-30mu`. If you not use `\mbox` with the screenshot you can see the difference of the size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}%<---------------added

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    f(x) &= \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \notag\\
    f(0) &= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right) \notag\\
    & \mkern-30
    mu\xlongequal[\mbox{‘‘}\frac{0}{0}\mbox{\quotedblbase}]{{\text{L' H}}} \lim_{x\to 0} \left( 
\frac{\cos(x)}{1} \right)\notag\\
 & \mkern-30
    mu\xlongequal[\text{‘‘}\frac{0}{0}\text{\quotedblbase}]{{\text{L' H}}} \lim_{x\to 0} \left( 
\frac{\cos(x)}{1} \right)\notag\\
    &= 1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the goal of the OP is to have the relations (`=` and `L'H=`) right-aligned.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah. Today for me is a ugly day :(. You use my \xlongequal as my example and I will remove my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes exactly. If I use your answer combined with this one, then you can achieve the same thing, however (at least from what i can tell) the `\xlongequal` uses =\joinrel= 4 times, so it is almost the same

Comment: I will pray for you, that it will improve.  Later today, we are getting 8cm of snow that I will have to drive home in.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes be very careful. I'm not understanding anything today.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the Effort!

Comment: +1 for the effort :)